# CORS error on localhost event with correct headers

Tags: express, google-chrome, http, cors, cloudflare-workers

I have a service that have the following headers on the response:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: *
```

My cloudflare worker

```
addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "-1",
  });

  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({
      network_address: request.headers.get("CF-Connecting-IP"),
    }),
    { headers: headers, status: 200 }
  );
}
```

We can check using cURL

`curl -s -D - -o /dev/null https://example.com`

```
HTTP/2 200
date: Thu, 02 Sep 2021 13:20:55 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 36
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: *
access-control-max-age: -1
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=HERU%2BxkJuLdgGnre4HxDofQDXnCZGbEsX4RVTaL%2FjmO%2FE0iIRY7UGEYvkBpL85g%2F7o3V4ZdbpNma48SpLg%2BZ%2FFnW4hIf%2F3tpNCfA4EocZCtYCOdNAsEooxBAww%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 688709d64bdc51f8-GRU
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400, h3=":443"; ma=86400
```

My code:

```
const response = await fetch(`//example.com/?_=${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}`)

const { network_address } = await response.json()
```

Unfortunately, on `localhost:3000` the browser was unable to do the request because of CORS, see bellow:

[image]

What I need to do to allow CORS on localhost?

Answer (score -3):

I just found another way, maybe try this

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

That will require CORS in your application by using pretty simple method actually.

Then

```
app.use(cors())
```

This will make your server use cors for whatever you wanna do with it

Then you can use:

```
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin:'your localhost URL'
    }
})
```

This will make CORS original location your website, URL,...

Combine all of that and it'll fix your problem.

(Sorry if my English's bad, I don't have Grammarly)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Justin explain your solution, why and how does it work, what is the issue and why does it need fixing. those kind of things